# use word in edit mode inside of iframe tag in web application

Tags: iframe, web-deployment, ms-wopi

i have a web application and i wanna display a word in edit mode
now i am using office live link in iframe tag like this:

```
<iframe src="https://onedrive.live.com/embed?resid=AD573EA91B1D07CB%21113&amp;authkey=%21AKgMcu7IQCZEWik&amp;em=2" width="476px" height="288px" frameborder="0">این یک <a target="_blank" href="https://office.com">Microsoft Office</a> سند جاسازی شده است که از طرف <a target="_blank" href="https://office.com/webapps">Office</a> ارائه شده است.</iframe>
```

and this file opened but in view mode not in edit mode.
can u help me!
if your solution is in python/C#/java or.... dosn't matter
Thanks and Have a Goodday!.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please share your https://<owaserver>/hosting/discovery file. Only then can we help you with the right link.

Comment: You cannot do it like this as per my knowledge. You have to use the WOPI protocol to enable editing on your own Website. Check below documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/cloud-storage-partner-program/online/